# routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: nginx

I use a PSP for payments, and when I use their webhook alert test it gives te following message: `routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

After reading up on people reporting similar issues (where mostly they are the ones that are request the URL, in this case it's an external service) it looks like this is a misconfiguration on Paddle's end? But I'm not sure since it looks like SSLv3 is very old?

My nginx server that listens for the incoming webhook has this in its config file:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
```

Is the problem that it doesn't have `SSLv3` for `ssl_protocols`? If so: it doesn't look like it's a good idea to add it?

**Update**
I changed my log level from `debug` to `info` and this is the result:

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking
```

And [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/905011/nginx-ssl-do-handshake-failed-ssl-error1417d18cssl) again indicates that this is then an issue on the PSP's end?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to update my server config with TLSv1.3 and add 2 cyphers, see [this issue](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-paddle/issues/11) on Github.